# Regex to match expression followed by lower case character

Tags: python, regex, calibre

I want to match a closing tag followed by an 0+ spaces/newlines followed by an opening tag when followed by a lowercase letter. Examples:

- `text</p> <p>blah` matches `</p>  <p>`
- `text</i><i>and more text <b>but not this</b>` matches `</i><i>`
- `text</i>      <i>And more text` does not match

I tried this: `</.*?>\s*\n*\s*<.*>(?=[a-z])`, but it doesn't work for the second example, as it will match `</i><i> and more text </b>` even though the question mark should make it "lazy".

Comment: Why not use a HTML parser instead? Regular expressions are *not* the tool to try and handle HTML; it'll lead to [pain and anguish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
</[^>]+>\s*<[^/>]+>(?=[a-z])
```

Change the '+' to '*' if you want to be able to match empty tags

Answer (score 0):

Making a quantifier lazy only makes the regex try the shortest possible match *first*, but if that doesn't work, it will gladly expand the match until the entire regex succeeds.

You need to be more specific in what you allow to match - for example by not allowing angle brackets inside a tag:

```
</[^<>]*>\s*<[^/][^<>]*>(?=[a-z])
```

(Also, `\s` already contains `\n`, so `\s*\n*\s*` can be shortened to `\s*`)